# If I have a 3D array how do I find the sum of values within a set boundary?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a 3D array such that:

```
int[][][] array = 
{  { {1,   2,  3}, { 4,  5,  6}, { 7,  8,  9} },
   { {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18} },
   { {19, 20, 21}, {22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27} } };
```

---

Now the array is as follows:

**First Output**

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

**Second Output**

10 11 12

13 14 15

16 17 18

**Third Output**

19 20 21

22 23 24

25 26 27

---

I would like to sum up the value in the 3 X 3 matrix boundary and create a new array such that one example of summation of the top left corner is such that:

**First Example**

((1+2+4+5)+(10+11+13+14)+(19+20+22+23))/ 12

The second example will be to take the centre value and compute the average

**Second Example**

((1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)+(10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18)+(19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27))/ 27

**New Output**

This will be how the values in the new array look:

12 12 13

13 14 14

15 15 16

where it will compute the average of all the values that are within a 3 by 3 square centered at the pixel.

Comment: What have you tried ?  please post some code

Comment: @LaurentB This is my first time dealing with 3D arrays so I am not too sure how does the 3D array works. Is there any useful links for me to find out more about multidimensional array? Will be grateful if you show me some links.

Comment: @宿命的な孤独 3D arrays works perfectly like 2D arrays. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Arrays dimension don't matter when you understand Arrays in programming, isn't like Math !

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Assignment, Try that may it helps you for Sample 1
I think sample 2 solution is clear

```
int sum=0;

for(int i : arr){
   for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
      for(int k=0;k<2;k++){
          sum+=arr[i][j][k];
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question shows that you're really treating the 3D array as an array of "images", each image being a 2D array.

You assignment/task is to create a 2D array, where the value of a cell is the sum of the same cell in each "image", plus the surrounding cells.

One way to achieve this is to break down the problem into smaller pieces of code.

First, create a method to sum the values of a cell (X, Y) across the "images", e.g. `sum(2, 0)` would be `3 + 12 + 21 = 36`.

Next, create a method to sum the values of a cell and the surrounding cells, such that:

```
sumWide(x, y) = sum(x - 1, y - 1) + sum(x, y - 1) + sum(x + 1, y - 1)
              + sum(x - 1, y    ) + sum(x, y    ) + sum(x + 1, y    )
              + sum(x - 1, y + 1) + sum(x, y + 1) + sum(x + 1, y + 1)
```

but taking care to not call `sum` for coordinates outside the "image".

Create another method to return the count of cells summed, e.g. `countWide(0, 0)` returns `4 * 3 = 12`.

Finally, create a method to build the result 2D array and calculate the values for each result cell as `sumWide(x, y) / countWide(x, y)`.